# OIDs (MIB) for Aruba 6000

Tags: snmp, aruba

I've got SNMP walk of some Aruba6000 routers, and on OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.14823.2.2.1.1.2.2.1.8
(staTransmitRate) it returns '13', but, in all MIBs I was able to find, possible values are 1-12.

What does value '13' mean? Or, where should I obtain some up-to-date MIB for this router? I looked Aruba's official site, and I wasn't able to find MIB with this value.

Comment: http://www.arubanetworks.com/support-services/aruba-support-program/contact-support/

Comment: I have the most recent MIB from Aruba (earlier this year) and it has the same values.  You're probably going to have to contact support, as Lex Li suggested.